# App Transport Security verbose

Tags: ios, xcode, app-transport-security

Is there a way to make App transport security more verbose?  When my app makes an http call I will get notified in the Xcode console.  However it doesn't tell me which http request is triggering the app transport security warning.

Is there a way to make the warning more verbose such that it includes the URL that triggered the warning?

Comment: Ideally you should not be using `http` at all.

Comment: That's true.  I am in the process of identifying which requests are http but I'm basically fishing in the dark.  It would be nice if Xcode could tell me which one, that way I can take action to turn that http to an https

Answer (score 7):

You can get this information by bumping up the CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS level

You can set it in your scheme's environment variables like so:

[image]

Or you can set it in your code (somewhere like at the beginning of `main`, for example) or even in your `applicationDidFinishLoadingWithOptions`. The code to increase the network logging is:

```
setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1);
```

The Xcode console shows the location of the log file:

> CFNetwork diagnostics log file created at:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/
>   Data/Application/C1A9DD23-B11E-F39A-E73A-5D837B2B2238/Library/Logs/
>   CrashReporter/CFNetwork_com.wottle.TestApp_821.nwlrb.log

Comment: This will tell me the exact URL request that triggered ATS?